# Sequelize doesn't create foreign keys as constraints

Tags: postgresql, sequelize.js

We're trying to create tables automatically inside PostgreSQL using Sequelize. Unfortunately, it doesn't create the foreign keys as constraints. Here is an example of one of my models:

```
module.exports = function(schema, DataTypes) {

    var definition = {
        id: {
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
            primaryKey: true,
            autoIncrement: true
        },
        deal_id: {
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER
        },
        image: DataTypes.STRING,
    };


    var image = schema.define('Image', definition, {
        tableName: 'images', // this will define the table's name
        timestamps: false, // this will deactivate the timestamp columns
        syncOnAssociation: true,

        classMethods: {
            getDefinition: function() {
                return definition;
            },
            associate: function(_models) {
                image.belongsTo(_models.Product, {
                    foreignKey: 'deal_id'
                });
            }
        }
    });

    return image;
};
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First, it's not uncommon for ORMs to handle this kind of thing internally rather than by using foreign key constraints in the database.

Second, it's not uncommon for ORMs to require a *pair* of association statements to trigger all the internal handling you might expect.

```
var Task = this.sequelize.define('Task', { title: Sequelize.STRING })
  , User = this.sequelize.define('User', { username: Sequelize.STRING })

User.hasMany(Task)
Task.belongsTo(User)
```

Finally, Sequelize will actually write foreign key declarations into the database, but only if you also declare some kind of action (or inaction) with `onUpdate` or `onDelete`.

> To add references constraints to the columns, you can pass the options
>   onUpdate and onDelete to the association calls. . . .

```
User.hasMany(Task, { onDelete: 'SET NULL', onUpdate: 'CASCADE' })

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Task` (
  `id` INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, 
  `title` VARCHAR(255), 
  `user_id` INTEGER REFERENCES `User` (`id`) ON DELETE SET NULL ON UPDATE CASCADE
);
```

[Code example source](http://sequelizejs.com/docs/1.7.8/associations#foreign-keys)

Comment: Thanks, clear answer. Didn't read that part in the documentation, my mistake. Thanks!

Comment: One problem left: how to define the foreignkey? If I add the foreignkey inside the object it doesn't create the constraints, if I don't it creates a camelCase foreignkey itself.

Comment: As I understand it, you don't define the foreign key in Sequelize. Instead, you set onDelete or on Update options in the association.

Comment: @Charlie: Thanks for catching the dead link. I think it just documents where I copied the last code block from. I couldn't find it on their current web site, and archive.org didn't seem to have a copy. I'll think about deleting it, but I'm also thinking about leaving the dead link in place as kind of documentation that Sequelize is indifferent to redirection and the effect of updating web pages.