# SequelizeDatabaseError: ER_ROW_IS_REFERENCED: Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails

Tags: sequelize.js

I set `FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS` to zero before syncing my model.
But I still get

> SequelizeDatabaseError: ER_ROW_IS_REFERENCED: Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sequelize.js: ER\_ROW\_IS\_REFERENCED: Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25891678/sequelize-js-er-row-is-referenced-cannot-delete-or-update-a-parent-row-a-fore)